# Is there anything wrong in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article

> In 2018, Japanese national soccer team called Samurai Blue took part in the World Cup held in Russia and won to the round of 16.

Is there anything wrong in the sentence? Should there be the definite article "the" before "Japanese"? If yes, then why?

Comment: You need an article before ***Japanese national soccer team*** (either ***the*** or ***a***, but the latter only works if we assume there could be more than one such team). That's because those four words collectively represent the ***subject*** of the verb ***called***. But note that this aspect of English syntax is unaffected by the presence of three adjectival elements before the "head noun" ***team***, so it's the same with ***A** team was disqualified, **The** team won both matches.* Also note that if the verb ***called*** is removed, you ***don't*** need any article at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the sentence does require an article before the word **Japanese**. It's because we don't talk about **team**.

We talk about **a team** or **the team**. The choice would depend on whether the writer thought that the intended audience were familiar with Samurai Blue. If **yes**, then use the definite article. If **no**, the indefinite. If unsure, use either one.

And the expression is NOT **win to the round**. It is **win through to the round** or **got through to the round**.

Finally, NOT **the round of 16**, just **to round 16** (or possibly the quarter finals etc, depending on how many rounds there were).

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/win%20through

Comment: Wouldn't "round 16" imply "the 16th round"?  "the final 16" might be a better choice (Quarter Finals would be the final 8).  Also, and I'm going back-and-forth on this: while "Japanese national soccer team called Samurai Blue" is clearly wrong, and "*the* Japanese national soccer team called Samurai Blue" is much better, would "Japanese national soccer team 'Samurai Blue'" (treating "Japanese national soccer team" in its entirety as an adjective for the pronoun "Samurai Blue") also be valid?

Comment: @Chronocidal Agreed, **round 16** is the 16th round as opposed to the **final 16** and there are in practice seldom 16 rounds. As to the alternative description of the team, I think it would work better in some contexts than others. Sports reporters frequently omit **articles** (and much else besides).